# Unmet Peer Dependency popper.js

Tags: jquery, npm

I'm having trouble using some ng-bootstrap dropdown component because of  dependency on jquery 3x which in turn cannot find popper.js

See this in my console

> Uncaught Error: Bootstrap dropdown require Popper.js

How do I get around this?

Install of jquery using npm shows the dependency on popper.js that's not in npm registry

> └── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY popper.js@^1.11.0

Here are my dependencies in package.json

```js
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
```

Comment: `popper.js` is just a `WARN`, bootstrap@4.0.0-beta installed without problems.

Comment: Yes bootstrap is installed but looks like it needs popper.js, my issue is that the bootstrap dropdown won't work. How do i get jquery to install with this popper.js that's not in npm registry? 


VM231:6 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap dropdown require Popper.js (https://popper.js.org)
    at eval (eval at webpackJsonp.../../../../script-loader/addScript.js.module.exports (

Comment: As stated on ng-bootstrap doc [here](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started), it has no dependency on jquery or bootstrap.js. Only dependencies are angular and bootstrap.css

Comment: Yes, that's what the documentation says.

Answer (score 17):

Popper.js can be now installed from npm:

```
npm install popper.js --save
```

Answer (score -1):

Might be you `dependencies` should be as below.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.1",
    "@bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta",
    "@core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "@font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "@jquery": "^3.2.0",
    "@rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "@zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
```

Hope I will work

Answer (score -2):

Found the answer here [bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap dropdown require Popper.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45661863/bootstrap-min-js6-uncaught-error-bootstrap-dropdown-require-popper-js)

Looks like popper.js is not in npm registry but theres a cdn to it, adding below to my apps index.html solves the dropdown issue

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Popper.js is available on npm (`npm i popper.js`)